# rails route to specific id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a pages controller with two records in the db; 'pages' and 'contact'.
The id for each page record is the title.
How do I write a specific route for each page?

I currently have a catch-all route which works...

```
match '/:id' => 'pages#show'
```

but I want to create a single route for each page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I probably don't understand your question because I have no idea why you would want to do that ;)

Anyhow, say you have a page what the title/id "about".  This is what your route could look like:

```
match '/about' => 'pages#show', :defaults => { :id => 'about' }
```

cf. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults

Note: I wouldn't call the route you're using already a "catchall"; it's a pretty normal Rails route.  This is what I would call a catchall:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

Comment: I want to specify them so I can have the path helpers, so I now have match '/about' => 'pages#show', :defaults => { :id => 'about' }, :as => :about

Comment: Gotcha.  Maybe you already considered this, but in the interest of not repeating code I would go with your original route, add `:as => :page` and use the path helper `page_path(:id => 'about')`.